# how can i format the sdcard android application

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

i want format sdcard  via android application

Comment: why you need to do this thing? there is a built in functionality to format your sd card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format your SD card from your phone.
Under Settings > SD card & phone storage > Format SD card.
refer to MediaFormat.java

you have to ensure what kind permission is suit for this action